# Does there exist an injection $f:\mathbb{R}\to P(\mathbb{N})$ that satisfies these conditions?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, cardinals, real-numbers

Does there exist an injection $f:\mathbb{R}\to P(\mathbb{N})$ from the reals into the power set of the naturals such that

1. for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ the set $f(x)$ is infinite, and
2. for any distinct $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$ the intersection $f(x)\cap f(y)$ is finite?

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for pointing that out. I have edited the question.

Comment: What is the context of this question?  What are your thoughts on the problem so far?

Comment: If it satisfies 1. and 2. it will be an injection automatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fix a bijection $\mathbf{N} \leftrightarrow \mathbf{Q}$. For each $x \in \mathbf{R}$ map it to a set of rational numbers $\{x_1,x_2,\dots\}$ corresponding to a sequence that converges to $x$. Call this map $f : \mathbf{R} \to P(\mathbf{Q})$. Then show that $f$ is injective, $f(x)$ is infinite and if $x \ne y$ then $f(x) \cap f(y)$ is finite.

Comment: I think this answers my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

First, get an injection $g : \mathbb{R} \to P(\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N})$ satisfying these conditions by setting $g(x) := \{ (n, \lfloor 10^n x \rfloor) : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$.  Now, using the fact that $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ is countable, can you see a way to convert $g$ to a function $f$ satisfying the conditions?

Comment: Why not $(n. [nx])$ to keep it simple ( and make all three solution provided practically equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

For each $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ consider the infinite strip
$$S_{\alpha} \colon \alpha x \le y \le \alpha x + 1$$

Each $S_\alpha$ contains infinitely many points from $\mathbb{Z}^2$ : indeed, it contains at least one point from each vertical. However, for $\alpha \ne \beta$, $S_{\alpha} \cap S_{\beta}$ is compact, so the intersection contains finitely many integral points.

[image: strips]